# Pandas: how to fill empty cells with its previous row value given a line number condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

there is several questions on stackoverflow regarding how to fill empty cells with previous row values. However in my case I have a dataframe in this format:

| Date | Val1 | Val2 | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7.1 | 3 | 12 | 15 |
| 8.1 | 3 |  | 3 |
| 9.1 | 3 |  | 3 |
| 10.1 | 5 | 10 | 15 |
| 11.1 | 6 | 12 | 18 |
| 12.1 | 5 | 11 | 16 |
| 13.1 | 4 | 10 | 14 |
| 14.1 | 6 | 13 | 13 |
| 15.1 | 6 |  | 6 |
| 16.1 | 6 |  | 6 |

On the left side, I have a date, for the val1, the values stay the same as Fridays over the weekends (6th and 7th in this case), however for the val2, it is empty. I would like in this case copy the 13 to the empty cells. However, in my data, the val2 is available only from a certain date so I want it to only spawn the previous row number given a certain condition (i.e. start spawning from date > 10.1 or the row > 4 or something like this) Is this possible?
thanks

Comment: You need to provide a better example, (there is no date 10.12.2012 nor row 1550, please provide a minimal example with realistic data and the matching expected output)

Comment: how am I supposed to paste 45000 rows on stack overflow? But fairs, I can change the question

Comment: Thus the **minimal** example, you can craft an example with 15 rows that summarizes the issue. With your current example I would say, just `fflll` the data

Comment: I edited hope it makes it clearer, and also I explicitly mentioned why ffill wouldn't work, cuz of the given conditon

Comment: Much better example, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) with boolean masks for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). This will give you a lot of flexibility to decide which rows should be filled or not:

```
m1 = df['Date'].gt(10.1) # you can do the same with datetime
m2 = df['Val2'].isna()

df.loc[m1&m2, 'Val2'] = df['Val2'].ffill()
```

output:

```
   Date  Val1  Val2  Sum
0   7.1     3  12.0   15
1   8.1     3   NaN    3
2   9.1     3   NaN    3
3  10.1     5  10.0   15
4  11.1     6  12.0   18
5  12.1     5  11.0   16
6  13.1     4  10.0   14
7  14.1     6  13.0   13
8  15.1     6  13.0    6
9  16.1     6  13.0    6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, for the gt function parametr, shouldnt be a string? Or what do I do if I have date format of 2022-07-12 cuz when I do that, it says leading zeroes in decimal int literals are not permitted, use an 0o prefix for octal ints

Comment: Well, it depends which dtype you have, and your example is ambiguous (I assumed floats), please update with a DataFrame constructor, but you can use many types. If you have dates as datetime or strings as YYYY-MM-DD you can use a simple comparison to a string

Comment: yeah it was floats in the beginning but I switched to datetime now in the form of YYYY-MM-DD, by simple comparisong you mean `m1=df['Date']>2022-01-10` ?

Comment: With a string! `2022-01-01` is invalid python (integers with leading zeros): `df['Date'].gt('2022-01-10')`

Answer (score 0):

If you have many rows of dates, then it would be best to figure out if a date falls on the weekend, and if so `shift()` the Friday values into `val2`:

```
# converts day to number (0-6)
df['day_of_week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.dayofweek

# if Saturday get the previous row
df['sat_value'] = df.loc[df['day_of_week'].shift(-1)==5, 'val2']
df['sat_value'] = df['sat_value'].shift(1)

# if Sunday get from 2 rows previous
df['sun_value'] = df.loc[df['day_of_week'].shift(-2)==6, 'val2']
df['sun_value'] = df['sun_value'].shift(2)

# fill in val2 based on sat_value and sun_value
conds = [
    df['sat_value'].notnull(),
    df['sun_value'].notnull()
]
choices = [df['sat_value'], df['sun_value']]
df['val2'] = np.select(conds, choices, df['val2']) # by default fill val2 itself
```